# Moving questions from Webmasters to Wordpress should be used sparingly

Tags: discussion, off-topic, migration, moderation

The Webmasters stackexchange is where webmasters hang out. The audience includes people knowledgeable in PHP, SEO, server issues, HTML (helpful with WordPress widgets), and lots of other areas that are relevant to admining a WordPress site.

On the other hand, the [WordPress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is sparsely populated, questions don't get many views, and much fewer answers. The audience is small and narrow. Therefore, I find it questionable when a user intentionally asks a WordPress-related question on Webmasters and the question gets moved to WordPress (where it often just dies).

There is too much overlap, and the WordPress stackexchange is not a full-fledged experience. Moving questions there suppresses valuable discussion. All WordPress admins are webmasters. Therefore, let them be and see the title of this post.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there's different sites in the SE network is to organize content. There may be overlap with the skillsets of the people who visit each site, but the domains they cover have very little overlap. WordPress goes there, Webmastery Things™ go here.

It's a shame the WordPress site is not very active as I know it's come in handy for me more than once when dealing with WordPress related issues. But regardless of its level of activity, the powers that be (e.g. Stack Exchange) have an open, "active" site specific for WordPress related questions and that's where they want those questions to be.

Furthermore, keeping WordPress questions on our site will only further exacerbate the inactivity problem for the WordPress site. They need new content if they are ever to grow the audience of that site.

Comment: I am a webmaster.  Some of my sites are WordPress, others are not.  Most issues among platforms are common or the same, especially when you are editing PHP or CSS or running quieries, or optimizing apache.  I don't understand why SE separated the sites other than the inherent bias against WP among SE users who consider themselves "hardcore" devs and WP users softies.

Comment: They are separated because, at the time, Stack Exchange was trying to create as many sites as they could in an effort to generate more revenue. If a site went through the proposal, review, and beta phases and generated enough community activity it became a permanent site. WordPress obviously crossed that threshold and here we are.

Comment: "the WordPress site is not very active" - Maybe it's just that those who (are able to) answer the questions are _absent_? Otherwise, [the stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) seem to suggest that WordPress SE is far more "active" than Webmasters SE?? 3 times as many questions/answers, almost twice as many registered users, 10 times as many visits/day! 9 questions and 2 answers posted on WordPress in the last day, whereas just 2 questions (and 2 answers) posted on Webmasters. (?)